# Perl if statement confusion

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

This code is an `if` statement; I want to test whether `$rtgene` contains `trn`. 
I tested the code with `$rtgene= nad3`:

```
if ($rtgene!~/trn/){
$end=$data[$i][0]+100;
}
else{
$end =$data[$i][1];
}
print $end;
```

This is an alternative expression that doesn't work:

```
($rtgene!~/trn/)? $end=$data[$i][0]+100 : $end=$data[$i][1]; print $end;
```

The problem is in the first code (normal if else statement) it works and give me the expected results, but the alternative one (last line) it's not working; it always executes the `else` statement.

**Question**: What is the cause of this problem? How to fix it?

Comment: I believe @ysth's answer is correct. Aside from that, why not just use the if/else statement? What benefit do you gain from using the `?:` operator instead? You might also consider reversing the condition; using a negative condition like `!~` in an if/else statement can be confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are trying to assign one of two values to `$end` based on a condition, why not write the conditional expression like that:

```
$end = ($rtgene !~ /trn/) ? $data[$i][0]+100 : $data[$i][1];
print $end;
```

This avoids the precedence problem accurately diagnosed by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) and is quite a bit easier to understand.

Perl can be used to write inscrutable code; it is not a good idea to make all your code inscrutable, though.  Stacking the assignment and print on a single line is tending towards inscrutability.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the way to use the ternary conditional operator:

```
$end = $rtgene !~ /trn/ ? $data[$i][0]+100 : $data[$i][1];
```

It evaluates the part before `?`, then returns the first option if this is true, otherwise it returns the second.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a precedence error to me.  = has lower precedence than ?:, so it is like:

```
( ($rtgene!~/trn/) ? $end=$data[$i][0]+100 : $end ) = $data[$i][1];
```

That is, either branch of the ternary assigns `$data[$i][1]` to `$end` (though the true branch assigns another value first that ends up being overwritten).

Try this instead:

```
($rtgene!~/trn/) ? ($end = $data[$i][0]+100) : ($end = $data[$i][1]);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can phrase it as `$end = ($rtgene!~/trn/) ? $data[$i][0]+100 : $data[$i][1]`

Comment: What @stevenl said.  The whole point of `?:` is that it's an expression, rather than a statement; it has a value, so you should use it.  Otherwise, it's clearer to just use `if`/`else`.